# Class 'session' not found in Webserver with Php 7.0

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

Estoy desplegando una aplicación desarrollada en *PHP* sobre un servidor *Linux Ubuntu 16.04* con *PHP 7.0* y *Nginx*.

Al momento de realizar autenticación en la aplicación, en el registro de errores de *Nginx* se presenta la siguiente línea:

> 2016/11/08 22:53:30 [error] 26138#26138: *58 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'session' not found in /data/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/httpdocs/html/validarusuario.php on line 4" while reading upstream, client: 10.0.0.59, server: localhost, request: "POST /validarusuario.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm-appmanagement.sock:", host: "10.0.1.37", referrer: "http://10.0.1.37/home.php"

Las línea a la que hace referencia el error es la siguiente:

```
<?php
    // Arma la sesi  n
    include "sesion.class.php";
    $session = new session();
    $session->inicio_sesion('_s', false);
```

¿Qué es lo que ocurre?

Comment: La verdad no soy adivina, pero creo que la clase 'session' no existe en "vaidarusuario.php".

Comment: Tu fichero se llama seguro `sesion.class.php` y no `session.class.php`? `sesion != session`

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas y mil disculpas por tardar tanto en avisar; pero ya lo solucioné, el error se debía a que la función open_short_tag estaba en Off.

Desde luego, le avisé al desarrollador que debía incluir correctamente los tags en los archivos.